eject or dismount volume (e.g., SD card) using system() in R
I'm working on a function in R that transfers files from an SD card to an external hard drive. At the end of the function, I'd like to dismount the SD card. Is it possible to use the system() function in R to do this?
The function I'm writing looks something like this:
sd_card_path <- 'D:/'
external_hard_drive_path <- 'E:/'

my_function <- function(sd_card_path, external_hard_drive_path) {

# copy files from SD card to external hard drive here...

# then dismount the SD card
# ideally, this would use the sd_card_path name above ('D') to select the volume with the same label
system(...)

}

This works using the command line outside of R:
diskpart  

list volume  

select volume 6 (again, I'd like to be able to select by my SD card label instead) 

remove all dismount  

exit

But not sure how to approach it within R...
Lastly, I'm using a Windows machine.

Use shell(), not system(), to send a command to the shell.  You may need to specify which shell to use.

Ok thanks @user2554330. Any thoughts on what those shell commands might be?

It should be whatever works in the shell outside of R.
